# Azure Cache for Redis Tier Options Difference

Tags: azure, redis

I have an already existing configuration of Azure Cache for Redis at hand, and it kind of bothers me. I would like a second opinion on the subject since I am new to Redis...

Our setup is cluster of 4 shards of P3 (26GB) instances.
At the Metrics page, when I choose "Used Memory" metric, and Apply Splitting by ShardId (to see all shards' memory usage at once), I see all the shards are between 240 and 250MB (this is the case for MAX memory usage for the 30 days, used memory does not seem to change at all).

If this metric shows the cache memory size, then this means we are using very little of what we are paying... I it does not show the cache memory, then please ignore all the assumptions and questions below, and please help me to find out where can I find the cache usage size.

I understand the need for using Premium tier, since it has higher specs for network and processing speeds than the Standard. But I don't understand why we upgraded from P2 to P3 since both have exactly the same characteristics except memory size (which we don't use at all).

Just want to make sure if there is something else between P2 and P3 options of Premium tier that I don't know about (couldn't find a difference going through the documentation, except for memory size).

**Q1:** If there is not, would it provide the same performance if we were to downgrade from P3 to P2 and keep the number of shards the same? (Save money but not compromise performance)

**Q2:** If I would like to gain more performance with this setup, would it be wise to downgrade to P2 and increase the number of shards? (From pricing perspective, 4 x P3 (26GB) and 8 x P2 (13GB) both provide the same memory size in the end but the network throughput and processing would be faster, am I right?)

**Q3:** If you have any other comments that would help me comprehend the situation at hand, please share your thoughts (Software, usage, any configuration details that I need to be aware of, etc...)

Thanks!